# Find intersection points between a segment and a convex polygon

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry, intersection

I'm trying to build a function in MATLAB, in which you input a **segment** (defined by two points) and a **polygon** (4-sides) by indicating on an array its vertices.

I have the following code:

```
function intersection = intersectSegmentPolygon (s, p)
% Create a vector with X coords of vertices and same for Y coords.
xv = [p(1,1) p(2,1) p(3,1) p(4,1)];
yv = [p(1,2) p(2,2) p(3,2) p(4,2)];
% Read the segment
x = [s.A(1) s.B(1)];
y = [s.A(2) s.B(2)];
[in,on] = inpolygon(x,y,xv,yv);
% Return vectors containing the coords of the intersecting points
intersection = [x(on), y(on)];
```

I am intersted in obtaining the points at the position `on` (the intersecting points) but, obviously the function is only checking the points A and B (the initial and final coordinates of the segment), what can I do in order to check all the points contained on the segment AB? Thank you.

Comment: This answer should contain everything you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657143/intersection-of-segment-with-polygon

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, but I had seen that similar question before and it didn't help me solve my problem. I have the function done already but I just need to check ALL the points of the segment AB, that's what I can't get to do.

Comment: Use the "2D Polygon edges intersection" or similar to calculate the intersection points. Then, for each segment between the intersection points, check if it's inside or outside your polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parametric equation of the line segment, `P = (1-t) A + t B`, with `0<=t<=1`.

Find the intersections between the polygon edges and the line of support of the segment, expressing the position of the intersection in terms of `t` (momentarily ignore the constraint on `t`).

You will find `0` or `2` intersections, not more, hence `0` or `2` values of `t`, forming an interval. The solution is given by the intersection of this interval with the interval `[0,1]`, an elementary 1D problem.